# Какие методы, прописанные/указанные в приложении, вызывает непосредственно Система, а не приложение?

Tags: android

Отметил в процессе чтения некоторой литературы для себя один тонкий нюанс о вызовах методов в `Android`-приложении, а именно то, что методы жизненного цикла `Activity` вызывает не приложение, которое мы реализуем и в которое их помещаем. Вызывает Система в зависимости от действий Пользователя или ситуации в Системе. Система оповещает этими методами приложение об изменении состояния. То есть, мы указываем в этих методах, что делать приложению, когда Система будет это приложение оповещать, в данном случае, о событиях изменения жизненного цикла.

Почему то раньше я не обращал на это внимание.

Интересно следующее. Какие еще методы, кроме методов жизненного цикла, прописанные/указанные в приложении вызывает непосредственно Система, а не приложение? Корректно ли вообще задавать такой вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем то все, что помечается `@override` и это идет не из наследников вашего класса относится к системе.

Конкретно по активити вы можете установить курсор на класс активити и нажать CTRL + O (*override metods ..*, так же в основном меню: *Code -> Override Metods*) и посмотреть, какие методы можно переопределить. В основном системный отклик - это колбэки, (как жизненного цикла), узнать колбэк можно по начальному *on-* в названии, как `onCreate()`.

Некоторые из колбэков, вызываемых системой (колбэки жизненного цикла не включены сюда):

`onConfigurationChanged()` - изменение в конфигурации (смена языка, ориентации, подключение устройств и тп.)

`onBackPressed()` - нажатие системной кнопки "назад"

`onSaveInstanceState()/onRestoreInstanceState()` - запись/восcтановление состояния

`onTouchEvent()` - касания экрана

`onRequestPermissionsResult()` - результат запроса разрешений

`onLowMemory()` - недостаточно памяти

Answer (score 0):

То, что вы называете системой, это по сути контейнер, в котором разворачивается какое-либо приложение. Контейнер получает запросы извне и создаёт по мере необходимости определённые объекты приложения. Т.е. не мы определяем момент создания объектов нашего приложения, а возможно даже и очерёдность их создания, а контейнер сам решает, какие объекты создавать и каков их жизненный цикл. Помимо вашего приложения у этого контейнера может быть ещё множество других приложений и, конечно, большое разнообразие системных переменных и объектов, о которых вообще можно не знать разработчику. Задача разработчика приложения - написать такое приложение, которое будет соответствовать требованиям данного контейнера. А задача разработчиков контейнера - создать контейнер, который реализует все необходимые интерфейсы, которые могут понадобиться запускаемым в нём приложениям.

Comment: стыдно признаться, но я ничего не понял. Вы это точно приминительно к андроид-разработке написали?